# How do I refresh a value in php from javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, variables

I have a form that I'm submitting using javascript.  However, one of the checks it does uses a php script that queries an API and gets a user's password.  This is for the purposes of form validation (i.e. if password doesn't match what we have on file..)

I'm using a php script to decode the password like this

```
function submitForm() {

    var options = {
        decoded_password: '<?php echo abc_decode($contactInfo['Password'])?>',
    }

    if (jQuery('#current_password').val() != options.decoded_password &&  $psc('#current_password').val()) {
        render_alert('Your current password does not match what we have on file.');
        return false;

    } else {
        $psc('#account-information').submit();
        document.getElementById("account-information").reset();
    }
```

Page loads, great, submit form, great. However, the variable is remembered from the first page load, so if I try to change the password again, it says my password doesn't match what is on file. If I reload the page, no problem.

Is there any way to change the value of `$contactInfo['Password']` in javascript without a page reload?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try making an AJAX call instead.  This won't require a page reload, but will still give you the opportunity to send the data back to the server.  If you store the data in the $_SESSION variable it will persist across multiple calls.

Comment: Could I get an example of how you would do that @OlfactoryNinja?  We have the session storing most data already.